# How to create trapezoide with concave side in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-shapes, shapes, concave

I am trying to create a trapezoide with one concave side.

I prefer a CSS3 solution which is cross-browser compatible and responsive.

I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921356/how-to-create-css-concave-convex-shapes) which provides a solution quite similar to my expected solution. However, I prefer the concave side not to be as round as it is in the provided solution, which I could not achieve so far.

Very important is that the shape supports an alpha channel (rgba) because I want to put an image behind the shape which should shine through the shape.

The solution should look as follows:

[image: Trapezoide with concave side]

Comment: What will be present on the other side of the shape? Does it have to show whatever is behind (as in be transparent)? How should the hover effects be? Should it be restricted to the shape boundaries or you don't any hover effects? Also did you attempt to modify that linked post to suit your needs?

Comment: @Harry The shape will be in front of an image. It should have a transparency. Hover is not needed. Yes, I tried to modify the fiddle in the linked post but I could not achieve to get the concave side as flat as I expect.

Comment: @Harry and the solution does not support transparency

Comment: Are you sure? Did you run that snippet? It shows the background image through the cut portion of the shape.

Comment: @Harry yes, you are right, transparency is indeed supported, however I could not achieve the flat concave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `div` to create a rectangle with the desired size. Set the `div` to `position: relative`and `overflow: hidden`.

Then use a pseudo-element with `position: absolute` and an opaque `box-shadow`.

```css
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg");
  padding: 50px;
}
#trapezoide{
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* Play with this properties to achieve the trapezoide just like you want. */
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

#trapezoide:before{
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px black;
  
  /* Play with this properties to achieve the trapezoide just like you want. */
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  top: -288px;
  right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="trapezoide"></div>
</div>
```

Adjust the indicated properties to make the trapezoide look just you want.

Comment: would be an appropriate solution if I would not need transparency, I didn't mention that before, sorry